# Why Laravel Passport does not generate oauth routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have a clean installation of Laravel 9.2.

```
composer require laravel/passport
```

Then I run the migrations and install passport.

```
php artisan migrate

php artisan passport:install
```

All of that should generate the necessary routes for authentication?

But route list does not have passport routes.

```
php artisan route:list
```

GET|HEAD   / .........................................................................................................
POST       _ignition/execute-solution .. ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionController
GET|HEAD   _ignition/health-check .............. ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController
POST       _ignition/update-config ........... ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController
GET|HEAD   sanctum/csrf-cookie ........................................... Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show

Did I missed something to work it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after `php artisan passport:install` you should call the `Passport::routes` method within the **boot** method of your `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`. This method will register the routes necessary to issue access tokens and revoke access tokens, clients, and personal access tokens:

```
public function boot()
{
  $this->registerPolicies();
     
  if (! $this->app->routesAreCached()) {
    Passport::routes();
  }
}
```

check the package [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport) for more details.